# Printing object properties in Powershell

Tags: powershell

When working in the interactive console if I define a new object and assign some property values to it like this:

```
$obj = New-Object System.String
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty SomeProperty "Test"
```

Then when I type the name of my variable into the interactive window Powershell gives me a summary of the object properties and values:

```
PS C:\demo> $obj
SomeProperty                                                                                                                                                                                  
------------                                                                                                                                                                                  
Test
```

I basically want to do just this but from within a function in a script. The function creates an object and sets some property values and I want it to print out a summary of the object values to the Powershell window before returning. I tried using Write-Host within the function:

```
Write-Host $obj
```

But this just output the type of the object not the summary:

```
System.Object
```

How can I have my function output a summary of the object's property values to the Powershell window?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Try this:

```
Write-Host ($obj | Format-Table | Out-String)
```

or

```
Write-Host ($obj | Format-List | Out-String)
```

Comment: I had to pass the `-Force` parameter to make it work, e.g. `Write-Host ($obj | Format-List -Force | Out-String)`

Comment: Ugh! It still displays horizontally on the screen.... if any output goes outside your buffer it just puts `...`. I have a love hate with POSH

Comment: Using `$objs = @();` and `$objs = $objs + $obj;`  I can use **`ConvertTo-Html`** : **$cols = $objs | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -Property Name, DataType, Default, Identity, InPrimaryKey, IsForeignKey, Description;**

Comment: This is perfect for debugging purposes as well, using `Write-Debug ($obj | Format-Table | Out-String)` :)

Comment: `Format-List` gives the best output :)

Comment: I have been wasting two days to figure this out, thank you very much.

Answer (score 69):

My solution to this problem was to use the [$() sub-expression block](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html).

```
Add-Type -Language CSharp @"
public class Thing{
    public string Name;
}
"@;

$x = New-Object Thing

$x.Name = "Bill"

Write-Output "My name is $($x.Name)"
Write-Output "This won't work right: $x.Name"
```

Gives:

```
My name is Bill
This won't work right: Thing.Name
```

Answer (score 24):

To print out object's properties and values in Powershell. Below [examples](https://www.codykonior.com/2013/03/26/powershell-how-to-show-all-of-an-objects-properties-and-values/) work well for me.

**$pool = Get-Item "IIS:\AppPools.NET v4.5"**

**$pool | Get-Member**

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#system.applicationHost/applicationPools#add

Name                        MemberType            Definition
----                        ----------            ----------
Recycle                     CodeMethod            void Recycle()
Start                       CodeMethod            void Start()
Stop                        CodeMethod            void Stop()
applicationPoolSid          CodeProperty          Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.CodeProperty
state                       CodeProperty          Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.CodeProperty
ClearLocalData              Method                void ClearLocalData()
Copy                        Method                void Copy(Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement ...
Delete                      Method                void Delete()
...
```

**$pool | Select-Object -Property * # You can omit -Property**

```
name                        : .NET v4.5
queueLength                 : 1000
autoStart                   : True
enable32BitAppOnWin64       : False
managedRuntimeVersion       : v4.0
managedRuntimeLoader        : webengine4.dll
enableConfigurationOverride : True
managedPipelineMode         : Integrated
CLRConfigFile               :
passAnonymousToken          : True
startMode                   : OnDemand
state                       : Started
applicationPoolSid          : S-1-5-82-271721585-897601226-2024613209-625570482-296978595
processModel                : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
...
```

Comment: Last variant of this worked for me best - can even shorten it to `$x | select *`, great for interactive.

Comment: I don't think this works if want to put it in a script. If so, I think you have to do something additional that what is stated in order to actually print it to the console (ie: Write-Output <something-something>)

Answer (score 12):

**[Tip #1](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-1)**

> Never use Write-Host.

**[Tip #12](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-12)**

> The correct way to output information from a PowerShell cmdlet or function is to create an object that contains your data, and then to write that object to the pipeline by using Write-Output.

*[-Don Jones: PowerShell Master](https://donjones.com/)*

Ideally your script would create your objects (`$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'SomeProperty'='Test'}`) then just do a `Write-Output $objects`. You would pipe the output to `Format-Table`.

```
PS C:\> Run-MyScript.ps1 | Format-Table
```

They should really call PowerShell PowerObjectandPipingShell.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I have accepted mjolinor's answer as I feel it answers the question more directly, however I learned a lot from the links you provided and agree that in most cases Write-Host is not suitable. Thanks!

Comment: The same technique will work, and would probably be more suitable used with Write-Verbose or Write-Debug.

Comment: I know, I'm many years late, but I disagree about `Never use Write-Host.` statement. You cannot use Write-Output inside functions that return data, because it will "pollute" this function. Simple example. Guess what ReturnText function will output? This is why I always use Write-host inside functions.

function ReturnText(){
  Write-Output "Some random message" 
  return "What I want to return"
}

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov I completely agree. For the purpose of logging information Write-Output should NEVER be used unless the Function is trivial. Once there is multiple function levels and you need to return output you MUST use something else, and Write-Host meets the bill.

Comment: Write-Host will also be immediately channeled back from a remote session allowing you to see progress, and if a remote session throws an error Write-Output information is lost.

Comment: Now there may be an argument to use Write-Verbose instead, or Write-Information, and maybe messages from these cmdlets do not get lost when a remote session throws back to the client. And this is particularly true since  Powershell 5.0, when Write-Host became a wrapper for the Information stream -  #6, with one very important difference: Write-Host is ALWAYS displayed. Write-Information depends on the $InformationPreference variable which defaults to SilentlyContinue.

And the importance of Write-Host being part of stream #6 is that it can now be redirected to a file, say.

Comment: Those Tips links are quite dead nowadays, so I had to check with the Internet Archive (https://web.archive.org/web/20151031065539/http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-12), since I wanted to check the other tips :D

Answer (score 12):

Some general notes.

---

#### `$obj | Select-Object` **⊆** `$obj | Select-Object -Property *`

The latter will show *all* non-intrinsic, non-compiler-generated properties. The former does *not* appear to (always) show *all* Property types (in my tests, it does appear to show the `CodeProperty` `MemberType` consistently though -- no guarantees here).

---

#### Some switches to be aware of for [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-5.0)

- `Get-Member` does *not* get static members by default. You also *cannot* (directly) get them *along with* the non-static members. That is, using the switch causes only static members to be returned:

  ```
  PS Y:\Power> $obj | Get-Member -Static

     TypeName: System.IsFire.TurnUpProtocol

  Name        MemberType Definition
  ----        ---------- ----------
  Equals      Method     static bool Equals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
  ...
  ```
- Use the `-Force`.

  > The `Get-Member` command uses the *Force* parameter to add the intrinsic members and compiler-generated members of the objects to the display. `Get-Member` gets these members, but it hides them by default.

  ```
  PS Y:\Power> $obj | Get-Member -Static

     TypeName: System.IsFire.TurnUpProtocol

  Name          MemberType     Definition
  ----          ----------     ----------
  ...
  pstypenames   CodeProperty   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection...
  psadapted     MemberSet      psadapted {AccessRightType, AccessRuleType,...
  ...
  ```

---

#### Use `ConvertTo-Json` for depth and readable "serialization"

I do *not* necessary recommend saving objects using JSON (use `Export-Clixml` instead).
However, you can get a more or less readable output from `ConvertTo-Json`, which also allows you to specify depth.

Note that not specifying `Depth` implies `-Depth 2`

```
PS Y:\Power> ConvertTo-Json $obj -Depth 1
{
    "AllowSystemOverload":  true,
    "AllowLifeToGetInTheWay":  false,
    "CantAnyMore": true,
    "LastResortOnly": true,
...
```

And if you aren't planning to read it you can `-Compress` it (i.e. strip whitespace)

```
PS Y:\Power> ConvertTo-Json $obj -Depth 420 -Compress
```

---

#### Use `-InputObject` if you can (and are willing)

99.9% of the time when using PowerShell: either the performance won't matter, or you don't care about the performance. *However*, it should be noted that avoiding the pipe when you don't need it can save some overhead and add some speed (piping, in general, is not super-efficient).

That is, if you all you have is a single `$obj` handy for printing (and aren't too lazy like me sometimes to type out `-InputObject`):

```
# select is aliased (hardcoded) to Select-Object
PS Y:\Power> select -Property * -InputObject $obj
```

```
# gm is aliased (hardcoded) to Get-Member
PS Y:\Power> gm -Force -InputObject $obj
```

**Caveat for `Get-Member -InputObject`:**
If $obj is a *collection* (e.g. `System.Object[]`), You end up getting information about the collection object itself:

```
PS Y:\Power> gm -InputObject $obj,$obj2
   TypeName: System.Object[]

Name        MemberType            Definition
----        ----------            ----------
Count       AliasProperty         Count = Length
...
```

If you want to `Get-Member` for each *`TypeName`* in the collection (N.B. for each `TypeName`, *not* for each object--a collection of N objects with all the same `TypeName` will only print 1 table for that `TypeName`, not N tables for each object)......just stick with piping it in directly.

Answer (score 2):

The below worked really good for me. I patched together all the above answers plus read about displaying object properties in the following link and came up with the below
[short read about printing objects](https://www.codykonior.com/2013/03/26/powershell-how-to-show-all-of-an-objects-properties-and-values/)

add the following text to a file named print_object.ps1:

```
$date = New-Object System.DateTime
Write-Output $date | Get-Member
Write-Output $date | Select-Object -Property *
```

open powershell command prompt, go to the directory where that file exists and type the following:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File is_port_in_use.ps1 -Elevated
```

Just substitute 'System.DateTime' with whatever object you wanted to print. If the object is null, nothing will print out.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Json to object
$obj = $obj | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-host $obj.PropertyName
```