# Using powershell's Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet is only returning the word "success" as a result

Tags: rest, powershell

I have written 2 scripts. One in python and one in powershell. Python is able to call a rest api and is returned the string "`JSESSIONID=8kfv0fi1bc84gtw2xvnqsrt4;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly` ". When I use the following code in powershell, it returns "success". What am I doing wrong?

```
$getEncCode = "Er6TmdhXn09Y9C1I"
$dataPart1 = @{EncCode=$getEncCode}
$dataPart = $dataPart1 | ConvertTo-Json                  
$uri = "https://10.164.42.77:8092/getEnc/2252953/login"                   
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12                   
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Body $dataPart -uri $uri  -ContentType "application/json"
Write-Host $result
```

Comment: Tempting Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792650/printing-object-properties-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Host $result` uses the `$result.ToString()` method to display that object as a string.

Likely there is more data there to show. Simply remove `Write-Host` to see it. Or do something like `Get-Member -InputObject $result` to see all immediate properties, methods etc.

Have a look at [Printing object properties in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792650/printing-object-properties-in-powershell) to see other ways to deal with this.